# How to register strongly typed signalR Hub in AutoFac for injecting IHubContext in IHostedService or BackgroundService

Tags: signalr, autofac, asp.net-core-3.1, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am a new user of signalR and Autofac. I am using signalR with ASP.NET Core Blazor Server and receiving the error listed below from a page that tries to connect to the hub. My Hub is strongly typed (IHubContext<Hub,Interface>) and is used within an IHostedService class implementation. It has a constructor that accepts an `ILogger` instance.

If I remove the constructor from the Hub implementation then the error does not occur. However, the IHubContext<Hub, IHub> appears not to be despatching to the clients in either case. The log message within the `SendMotionDetection` method on the hub is not displayed.

The official autofac [documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/signalr.html#owin-integration) recommends installing the [Autofac.SignalR](https://nuget.org/packages/Autofac.SignalR/) NuGet package for integration with signalR. However, upon installing the package it is targeted for frameworks :`.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8`. I am targeting `netcoreapp3.1` developing on MacOS.

**Question:**

How to register a strongly typed signalR Hub in AutoFac **ASP.NET Core 3.1** for the purpose of injecting IHubContext<Hub, IHub> in IHostedService or BackgroundService?

Currently, the IHubContext<Hub, IHub> injected parameter is not sending the `SendMotionDetection` message to all clients, i.e. the console log message from the hubs message is not displayed. Yet, no exception is being thrown???

**The error**

```sh
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler[1]
      Error when dispatching 'OnConnectedAsync' on hub.
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating WebApp.Realtime.SignalR.MotionHub.
 ---> Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.NoConstructorsFoundException: No accessible constructors were found for the type 'WebApp.Realtime.SignalR.MotionHub'.
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder.GetDefaultPublicConstructors(Type type)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder.FindConstructors(Type targetType)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.CreateInstance(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.CreateInstance(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubActivator`1.Create()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.OnConnectedAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.OnConnectedAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler`1.RunHubAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
```

Source code for the SignalR hub and Startup are listed below.
Within the `ConfigureServices` of `Startup.cs`, I have tried registering the SignalR Hub with autofac container registry but still getting the error. Interestingly, if I do not include a constructor for the SignalR hub the error does not occur. However, I am injecting an IHubContext into a background service and when sending a messages from the background service via the IHubContext it does not appear to be dispatching.

**Interface**

```
public interface IMotion
{
    Task SendMotionDetection(MotionDetection message);
}
```

**Hub**

```
    public class MotionHub : Hub<IMotion>
    {
        private ILogger<MotionHub> _logger;
        MotionHub(ILogger<MotionHub> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _logger.LogInformation("Motion SignalR Hub Created");
        }

        // send the motion detection event to all clients
        public async Task SendMotionDetection(MotionDetection message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("MotionHub => SignalR Hub => SendMotionDetection");
            await Clients.All.SendMotionDetection(message);
        }
    }
```

**Startup**

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public ILifetimeScope AutofacContainer { get; private set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddSignalR(o => o.EnableDetailedErrors = true);
            services.AddHostedService<MqttListenerWorker>();
            services.AddHostedService<ConsumerService>();
            services.AddLogging();
        }


        // ConfigureContainer is where you can register things directly
        // with Autofac. This runs after ConfigureServices so the things
        // here will override registrations made in ConfigureServices.
        // Don't build the container; that gets done for you by the factory.
        public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // Register your own things directly with Autofac here. Don't
            // call builder.Populate(), that happens in AutofacServiceProviderFactory
            // for you.
            builder.RegisterModule(new MotionDetectionRepositoryModule());
            builder.RegisterModule(new KafkaModule());

            //builder.RegisterHubs(typeof());
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MotionDetection).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

            builder.RegisterType<MotionHub>()
                .AsSelf();
            // builder.RegisterTypes(typeof(MotionHub).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            //     .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Hub"))
            //     .As(typeof(Hub<MotionHub>))
            //     .ExternallyOwned();
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<MotionHub>("/motionhub");
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
```

**IHostedService**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Confluent.Kafka.SyncOverAsync;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using WebApp.Data;
using WebApp.Data.Serializers.Contracts;
using WebApp.Kafka.Contracts;
using WebApp.Kafka.SchemaRegistry.Serdes;
using WebApp.Realtime.SignalR;


namespace WebApp.Kafka
{
    public class ConsumerService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        // At the time of writing Kafka Consumer isn't async so....
        // making a long running background thread with a consume loop.
        private Thread _pollLoopThread;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private ConsumerConfig _consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig();
        private HashSet<string> _cameras { get; }
        private string _topic;
        private IHubContext<MotionHub, IMotion> _messagerHubContext;

        private JsonDeserializer<MotionDetection> _serializer { get; }
        private ILogger<ConsumerService> _logger;


        // Using SignalR with background services:
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/background-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2
        public ConsumerService(
            IConfiguration config,
            IHubContext<MotionHub, IMotion> messagerHubContext,
            JsonDeserializer<MotionDetection> serializer,
            ILogger<ConsumerService> logger
        )
        {
            _logger = logger;

            config.GetSection("Consumer").Bind(_consumerConfig);

            // consider extension method for those settings that cannot be set in cnofig
            if (_consumerConfig.EnablePartitionEof != null)
            {
                throw new Exception("shouldn't allow this to be set in config.");
            }

            _consumerConfig.EnableAutoCommit = false;

            _topic = config.GetValue<string>("Topic");
            _messagerHubContext = messagerHubContext;

            _serializer = serializer;
            _cameras = new HashSet<string>();
            _cameras.Add("shinobi/group/monitor/trigger");
        }


        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("ConsumerService starting a thread to poll topic => {}...", _topic);
            _pollLoopThread = new Thread(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var consumerBuilder = new ConsumerBuilder<string, MotionDetection>(_consumerConfig);
                    consumerBuilder.SetValueDeserializer(_serializer.AsSyncOverAsync());
                    using (var consumer = consumerBuilder.Build())
                    {
                        consumer.Subscribe(_topic);

                        try
                        {
                            while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                            {
                                var consumerResult = consumer.Consume(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                                _logger.LogInformation("Consumer consumed message => {}", consumerResult.Message.Value);

                                if (_cameras.Contains(consumerResult.Message.Key))
                                {
                                    // we need to consider here security for auth, only want for user
                                    await _messagerHubContext.Clients.All.SendMotionDetection(consumerResult.Message.Value);
                                    _logger.LogInformation("Consumer dispatched message to SignalR");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }

                        consumer.Close();
                        _logger.LogInformation("Consumer closed, preparing to stop");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _logger.LogCritical("Unexpected exception occurred in consumer thread");
                    _logger.LogError(e, "Consumer Error");
                    // update to take remdial action or retry to ensure consumer is available
                    // during lifetime
                }
            });

            _pollLoopThread.Start();

            _logger.LogInformation("Consumer thread started");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }


        public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                _pollLoopThread.Join();
            });
            _logger.LogInformation("Consumer stopped...");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Consumer disposed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I have solved it.

The implementation of methods in the Hub class are invoked from *client->server*, so I would never see output from that because in this instance the server is pushing to the client.

For the time being I have changed the parameter to the method in *IMotion* interface to be a string and updated the code on the client blazor page to reflect a string parameter.

I also removed code that injects the Hub into autofac. I suspect that this is being handled by Microsoft DI automatically???

I think the issue might have been serialization/deserialization of object.

I have included the code below for the blazor page.

Next step is to work out how to serialize/deserialize object over signalR connection and also connect to the signalRHub after the page has been rendered instead of when it has been Initialized (executes twice!).

**Blazor Page**

```
@page "/"

@using System.Threading
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@using WebApp.Data


<h1>Blazor Server App</h1>

<div>Latest message is => @_latestMessage</div>

<div id="scrollbox">
    @foreach (var item in _messages)
    {
        <div>
            <div>@item</div>
        </div>
    }
    <hr />
</div>


@code {
    private HubConnection hubConnection;
    private string _latestMessage = "";
    private List<string> _messages = new List<string>();
    public bool IsConnected => hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var hubUrl = NavigationManager.BaseUri.TrimEnd('/') + "/motionhub";
        // Uri uri = NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/motionhub");

        try
        {
            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(hubUrl)
                .Build();

            hubConnection.On<string>("SendMotionDetection", ReceiveMessage);

            await hubConnection.StartAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Index Razor Page initialised, listening on signalR hub url => " + hubUrl.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Hub Connected => " + IsConnected);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Encountered exception => " + e);
        }
    }
   
    private void ReceiveMessage(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hey! I received a message");
            _latestMessage = message;
            _messages.Add(_latestMessage);

            StateHasChanged();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("An exception was encountered => " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```